# Can I multiply a string with an integer in php?

Tags: php-7.4

I declare a variable and assign it a value
`$var = "wombat"`

The output I want `wombatwombatwombat`

I tried

```
$var = "wombat" * 3;
echo $var;
```

Like python, would this work in php?

Comment: `$var x 3`. Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024522/can-perl-do-multiplying-a-string-like-python

Comment: I looked it up, however its not the case, it doesnt work in php 7.4.8 I wanted to repeat the string and for this I found the ```str_repeat()``` function.